# PostgreSQL with Grails auto increment issue

Tags: postgresql, grails, auto-increment

```
class abc{

   Integer id
   String name
}   

class xyz {


   Integer id
   Integer project_id
   String name
}
```

When I save object of abc object save successfully with some id (say 12 ) now when I save object of xyz its id increment to (abc.id+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails uses a sequence [hibernate_sequence] to assing the id for the new objects persisted to the database, is you want to assign a different kind of id you should read the [grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#identity).

Comment: See [this post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/One-hibernate-sequence-is-used-for-all-Postgres-tables-td1351722.html) by Burt for a copy/paste solution.